# Changing UserAgent of WKWebView after webView has loaded

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, wkwebview

**Previous Title**: Completely restarting a WKWebView after runtime

I am trying to implement a feature that allows for the user to request a desktop site of a URL in the WKWebView. If I'm not mistaken, this can only be done by resetting the UserAgent programatically, and then *restarting* (not sure what the correct term to use here is) the UIWebView altogether.

The UIWebView is setup in the Interface Builder and connected through an IBOutlet. Does anyone know where I would start? I am trying to implement this into a function.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I figured out the simple answer to my question after a bit of debugging. You can literally set the custom user agent and reload the web page. Extremely simple. Here's some sample code via a function:

```
func requestDesktop() {
        // Set Desktop UserAgent
        let desktopAgent: String! = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/602.3.12 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0.2 Safari/602.3.12"
        webView.customUserAgent = desktopAgent
        webView.reload()
}
```